# WinSCP: How to update the "Changed" information if a sub-folder has been changed?

Tags: filesystems, winscp

I have a `Folder_A`, which has a `Folder_B`, which has a file `File_C`.

When `File_C` is changed, the `Folder_B` also updates its "changed" record, but `Folder_A` is not updated.

I wonder how the "changed" record can also be updated for `Folder_A`?

I just tested, it seems to work in this way: if the content of `File_C` is changed without changing the file name of `File_C`, the timestamp of `File_C` changes, the timestamp of `Folder_B` does not change; if the file name of `File_C` changes but without changing the content of `File_C`, the timestamp of `File_C` does not change but that of `File_B` would change.

Comment: The *contents* of folder b have changed. The *contents* of folder a have not changed so what you want to happen is probably not possible.

Comment: What system does your server use? What protocol are you using with WinSCP? Those information is missing in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with WinSCP. It's all about the remote system and its file system.

On most systems, modification time of a directory is the last time, when the directory changed. And "directory" is a *list* of files. So the timestamp shows time when the *list* changed the last time. I.e. the last time you have added/removed/renamed a file.

So I do not even think that your are correct here:

> When `File_C` is changed, the `Folder_B` also updates its "changed" record.

A change to a file does not change anything about its parent directory. Unless you are using some unusual system.

There's hardly anything you can do about it. Except for developing a service on the server that would update the timestamps the way you want.

Comment: When `File_C` changes, `Folder_B` of course changes its "changed" record. But `Folder_A` does not change. You can test it on a windows system for the "Date modified" record of a folder.

Comment: No it does not, here is a proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPzfu.png

Comment: Do you mean, when the `File_C` was created, the `Folder_B` was updated. But when `File_C` was modified, the `Folder_B` was not updated?

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer says!

Comment: I tested it on my Win as well, please see the updated question about changing the name and content of the file.

Comment: That's correct. Again, as my answer says: *"the last time you have added/removed/ **renamed** a file."* - Though it does not change anything about your question, nor my answer.

Comment: I see, only added/removed/ renamed a file, but not modified a file. Is there a way to see the modification of a file on the timestamp of a folder?

Comment: Again, see my answer: *"There's hardly anything you can do about it. Except for developing a service on the server that would update the timestamps the way you want."*